# Change notification text and background color

Tags: notifications

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the text that appears on the notifications in the notification drawer.

I'm running CM12.1 with Xposed.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7320604/1432355

Comment: @kimimsc this is how to change it when you're making your own application

Comment: ah,  I thought that's what you wanted... My bad

Comment: @kimimsc Android Enthusiasts forum is for users, not for programmers.  So, he wanted to modify the system setting.